# Daemonizing node.js with child processes using cluster, setuid/setgid?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cluster-computing, daemon

When daemonizing a nodejs app that forks child processes, is there an option in cluster.fork() that allows for setting the user:group of the child?  For the master process, I set the user and group to a non-root user:

```
kue.app.listen(kueport, function() {
    process.setgid("uocoder");
    process.setuid("uocoder");
});
```

Forking the child processes:

```
// FORK over all available cores
var clusterWorkerSize = require('os').cpus().length;  // Get number of cores
console.log("Forking over all " + clusterWorkerSize  + " cores");

for (var i = 0; i < clusterWorkerSize; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
}
```

When running as a daemon using an [init.d script](https://www.exratione.com/2013/02/nodejs-and-forever-as-a-service-simple-upstart-and-init-scripts-for-ubuntu/), the child processes are run as the root user, while the master is using the uid and gid I set in the code.

```
$ ps aux | grep uocoder
uocoder   1484 20.5  0.6  42348 23632 ?        Sl   07:59   0:00 /usr/bin/nodejs /home/uocoder/uocoder/app.js
root      1487 21.5  0.5  40040 20812 ?        Sl   07:59   0:00 /usr/bin/nodejs /home/uocoder/uocoder/app.js
root      1489 21.0  0.5  40040 20808 ?        Sl   07:59   0:00 /usr/bin/nodejs /home/uocoder/uocoder/app.js
```

I havent found a way to set the uid and gid of the child processes in the [cluster docs](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_settings), maybe I overlooked something?

Answer (score 0):

Created github issue, fixed by [pull 7882](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/7882):

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7881